# react on receipt of local notification

Tags: ios8, uilocalnotification

I'm scheduling a local notification and would like to react to the receipt of it; it works as expected when the app is in the foreground, via `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`, but I can't get it to work when the app is in the background or closed - even if the app is in the background, that method is never called, neither is `handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:`.

How can I achieve that an action is executed for sure at a specific time?

I would like to react to the local notification even if the user doesn't tap on the notification, so do something automatically when the local notification was received.

Answer (score 0):

Generally notifications are received in two cases.

**case-1**: In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, if the app is neither running nor in the background

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];  
        if (localNotif) {       
            // handle here
        }
}
```

**Case-2**: In `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method if the app is either running or in background.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif
{
    if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive )
     {
       NSLog(@"app not running");
     }
     else if(app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
      NSLog(@"app running");
    }
}
```

Comment: that's what I would expect; but ```didReceiveLocalNotification:``` isn't called when the app is in the background - what could I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for my late response.
Until and unless you tap on a notification, delegate method will not called (As per Apple documentation). I tried this with a demo project. But its not possible.